# how to pass data from php to javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am designing a forum and i want it look dynamically. I have made the form details getting stored in ajax successfully. but i want the data to be displayed in the page after the data get stored. i don't want the page to reload. Is it possible?

this is my html code

```
 <form class="col s12">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s4">
                <i class="tiny material-icons prefix">subject</i>
                <input type="text" id="icon_prefix2"  name ="heading" required></input>
                <label for="icon_prefix2">Heading for your discussion</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s8">
                <i class=" tiny material-icons prefix">mode_edit</i>
                <input type="text" id="icon_prefix2"  name ="discussion" required></input>
                <label for="icon_prefix2">Start your discsussion</label>
                <input type="submit" class="btn waves-effect waves-light right" value="post">
            </div>

        </div>
    </form>
<div class="subheading">
    Posted Discussions
</div>
```

on clicking post.it gets stored using the following script and toast message will pop up on posting. the code is

```
$(function () {


    $('form').on('submit', function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'cardiosubmit.php',
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            success: function () {
                myFunction()

            }

        });

    });

});
```

how shall i make the data from db on the page after posting the form.?

Comment: and where did u define `myFunction` ?

Comment: thats nothing but a toast that will show "successfully posted"

Comment: And where do u wanna display the results or discussion? I don't see a holder for your discussion in the design

Comment: i ve edited it now. i want it to be displayed on the div "posted discussions". i m a beginner in stackoverflow so i didn't know how to ask properly what are all the details required yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can return json from your php script having all data you need and print it in your page.

In your php file:

```
//after saving data to db
$html = '<div>';
$html .= '<span>Field:'.$valueOfFieldYouWantToDisplay.'</span>';//add more if needed.
$html .= '</div>';
return json_encode($html);


$(function () {


$('form').on('submit', function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'cardiosubmit.php',
        data: $('form').serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
            myFunction();
            $('.subheading).html(data.html);
            // returnedHtml is Data/HTML from your php. It can be in form of a thread.

        }

    });

});
```

});

Comment: can you refer any links for implementation sample? because i m new to json and ajax.

Comment: No i m not using any

Comment: i did the same. there are no errors but this line " $('.subheading).html(data.html);
" is not displaying anything

Comment: Is data saving in DB? Can you send me your code php, js and html?

Comment: its saving in db..wait i ll send you, can you tell me your email ID or something to send?

Comment: please check your mail

Comment: check your mail

Answer (score 0):

Here you will get some idea to insert and get data without refreshing page

```
// Insert data
$(function () {
    $('form').on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'cardiosubmit.php',
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            success: function () {

                // Call function to get all the data.
                getAll()
            }
        });
    });
});

// Get data
function getAll()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'getcardiodata.php',
        data: $('form').serialize(),
        success: function () {
        //Now, your all the data will get by ajax responce. which is appent in the html format.
            $("#Responce").htlm();
        }
    });
}
```

**getcardiodata.php**

```
<?php
    /*
     * Your logic to get data from the database 
     * simple return/echo your database result
     * its return in the ajax success responce
     */

?>
// Your result where you want to display data
<div id="Responce"></div>
```

Comment: this will get data even if insert fails

Comment: you can check condition while you call the getAll function. If data not inserted then simple return false and avoid calling function.